# Kotlin WebView callback parameter is always null

Tags: javascript, kotlin, webview

#### I'm trying to create a native-web bridge for an android application that partially uses a webview.

My issue is that while I've created the @JavascriptInterface, and have the corresponding code setup on the web, the web's callback function is always hitting the native side as `null`.

Test kotlin function:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun testAsync(message: String, callback: ((String) -> Unit)?) {
    println("Async Message: $message")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("Async Callback delivered")

    callback?.let { it(message) }
}
```

With this `?.let{ }` check, nothing happens given the callback is always `null`, however when I act as if it isn't `null`, I get the following warning in the IDE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.grubhub.core.WebViewInterface.testAsync, parameter callback
```

The interface is setup as such:

```
addJavascriptInterface(WebViewInterface(context), "Hybrid")
```

Lastly, the web code is calling this from a test button, but runs this function:

```
Hybrid.testAsync("Hello World", (message) => {
    Hybrid.showToast(message);
})
```

I can't find any documentation on how Android WebViews handle these callbacks, and I'm not using `evaluateJavascript()` on the native side to run anything, simply exposing native functionality to the web side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass only primitive types and `String` objects as parameters of a method passed as `@JavascriptInterface` from JS code, so **there is no way to pass a lambda to this method from your JS code.**

Comment: Hmm that's so interesting. Do you know where I can find any documentation as to why we can only pass primitive types? That's very disappointing and seems like a major oversight, however I'd like to learn more about that.

Comment: I didn't find such information on official Android documentation. But Android apps can interact with WebView to call JS code only with methods `WebView.evaluateJavascript()` and pass some JS code through `WebView.loadUrl(string)`. The solution you're proposing is impossible perhaps due to crossplatform issues (Android can't call JS code with a way different from I described). But probably you have a good feature request for Google team :)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Yeah definitely would be a great feature, though I'm not sure if there are inherent security risks with that.